# C array/pointer semantics: how to make an array inside a struct to have properties/semantics of corresponding pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99, semantics

Consider this code:

```
void f_01( int a, char** flags )
{
    printf("flags %p\n", flags);
    if ( ! flags ) 
    {
        return; // early exit
    }
    //some code
}

struct s01
{
    int     a;
    char**  flags1;     /* NULL = not used  */
    char*   flags[];    /* NULL = not used  */
} s_01 = { 13 };

int main()
{
    struct s01* s = &s_01;
    f_01( 1, NULL );
    f_01( 2, s->flags1 );//for demonstration purpose
    f_01( 3, s->flags ); //s->flags is expected to be NULL, but instead
                         //it evaluates to address of s->flags (i.e. &s->flags)
    return 0;
}
```

Actual output:

```
f_01 1 (nil)
f_01 2 (nil)
f_01 3 0x601038
```

Expected output (imaginary):

```
f_01 1 (nil)
f_01 2 (nil)
f_01 3 (nil)
```

Question: how to make an array struct member (`flags` in the example) to have properties/semantics of corresponding pointer (`char**` in this example), i.e. to be initialized to `NULL` by default?

The purpose of this: to be able to use the same logic in the API's implementation (`f_01` in this example) with `char**` argument for both `NULL` pointers and `empty arrays`. I.e. inside the API there is NO additional `if (! *flags)` check because it is expected that if `flags != NULL` then it is `non-empty array`. It is logical, right? Then why need to add additional `if (! *flags)` check to handle `empty arrays`? Can an `empty array` be evaluated somehow to `NULL` pointer in C?

Comment: Array cannot be NULL. What is the purpose of this? I believe there is more convenient way to achieve what you seek.

Comment: Your `flags` member isn't an "empty array"; there's no such thing in C as far as I know. It is a *flexible array member*; are you familiar with how those work?  They really only make sense when you are allocating the struct dynamically.  When you allocate it statically, as in your example, it behaves like an array of length 1 whose element may not be accessed.  But it definitely has an address and is not NULL.

Comment: I don't understand why the behavior you describe would be useful, and in any case I am pretty sure there is no way to get it.

Comment: But note this also means that if you do add `if (!*flags)` in your `f_01` function, then you are invoking undefined behavior when you call it on `s->flags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the struct doesn't initialize the `flags` as `NULL` is because the last flags is "flexible array member" and not a pointer. The struct is a way of allocating enough space for all of the things that you want to put in it. So, when the struct has `int a;`, `char** flags1;`, `char* flags[];`. It needs to allocate a chunk of memory that is at least `sizeof(a)`(probably 16 bits), `sizeof(char**)` (probaly 32 bits), and `sizeof(char*[])` (in this particular case it is unknown). Because we don't know the size of the array of pointers yet, it will treat it as if it is zero bits and you will need to allocate enough additional bits for the size of the array when you figure out the size you need. (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf §6.7.2.1 18-21)

So in this case it initializes the `char*` pointer as `NULL` because it wasn't given a value and assumes you want an array of `char*` that is zero in size because it wasn't given a value for its size. This array simply starts at the end of of the struct (in your case `0x601038`). So when you pass the array into `f_01` you are giving it the starting location of the zero array.

I know that you probably don't want to hear this but the only solution that I can think of is to replace that `char*   flags[];` with `char** flags`. Maybe you could make `char* flags[];` change into `int sizeOfFlags;` and `char* flagData[];` then just feed sizeOfFlags into f_01. because `NULL == 0` if `sizeOfFlags == 0` it will still give you `NULL` when the size is zero. However that is definitely the wrong way to do it.